# laravel validation fail without min

Tags: php, laravel, validation

everybody, I have My Validation line here

```
   'governorate'=> 'required|string',
```

and in My Form, if I left it empty it passes the validation and not getting any error but when I use

```
        'governorate'=> 'required|string|min:10',
```

it works any Solve Please because I can't use min:10 for some reasons

My App\http\karnel

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    // \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    // \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
];
```

Comment: Does it work if you use size:10 instead of min:10?

Comment: What happens when you try, and what is some of the strings of `governorate` that's passing/failing?

Comment: @LukeG. yes it worked

Comment: @aynber  passing when using min:10

Comment: @apokryfos laravel 5.7

Comment: You've commented out `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` so if the input is empty you get a `''` value which is a valid string. You need to use `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` to get this to correctly require the field to not be empty

Comment: @apokryfos I tried Now but did't Work